# Can I show twitter/instagram posts in Ckeditor5 without using Embedly and Iframely

Tags: angular, ckeditor, embed, ckeditor5

In my project I use ckeditor5 to create articles. I want to add twitter, instagram posts in articles, but can not. When I create article and insert , for example, https://twitter.com/ckeditor/status/1027571541989572612 this post, in creating mode it looks :
[image]

But after saving my article and clicking on it to view it, post is not showing. In inspector I see the following code:

```
<figure class="media"><oembed url="https://twitter.com/ckeditor/status/1027571541989572612"></oembed></figure>
```

In documentation I read that I shoul use  Embedly or Iframely services to displaying posts. Can I do this without using these services? P.S. Inserting youtube video I could only after setting in config this field :

```
mediaEmbed: {
        previewsInData: true,
    }
```